# Elasticsearch ignores my index template mappings when creating new index

Tags: elasticsearch

No matter what I do, when the index is created with a heartbeat process (7.10.2)
Elasticsearch maps all fields and the monitor.id will be like:

```
GET /heartbeat-7.10.2-2021.05.25
[...]
         "monitor" : {
          "properties" : {
            "id" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
[...]
```

even if i delete the index, template, and update the template as:

```
{
    "order" : 1,
    "index_patterns" : [
      "heartbeat-7.10.2-*"
    ],
    "settings" : {
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic": false,
      "properties" : {
        "monitor" : {
          "properties" : {
            "id" : {
              "ignore_above" : 1024,
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "aliases" : { }
  }
```

It appears to be that template configuration is ignored.
There is no other heartbeat template.
This is problematic, because in this way I cannot use e.g. monitor.id for aggregation. This is a problem with multiple fields.

I'm relatively new to templates, so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you show what you get from `GET _cat/templates?v` ?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I had both _template and _index_template and the _index_template had the priority

After

```
delete _index_template/heartbeat*
```

it works just fine.